# What is the best way to get rid of common substring prefix in Python3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, substring

Let's assume we have string and a list of strings:

String:

- `str1 = <common-part>`

List of strings:

```
[<common-part>-<random-text-a>, <common-part>-<random-text-b>]
```

What is the best (in case of readability and code-purity) to get such a list:

```
[<random-text-a>, <random-text-b>]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would compute the common prefix of all strings using `os.path.commonprefix`, then slice the strings to remove that prefix (this function is in `os.path` module but doesn't check path separators, it's useable in a generic context):

```
import os

p = ["<common-part>-<some-text-a>", "<common-part>-<random-text-b>"]
commonprefix = os.path.commonprefix(p)

new_p = [x[len(commonprefix):] for x in p]

print(new_p)
```

result (since `commonprefix` is `""<common-part>-<"`):

```
['some-text-a>', 'random-text-b>']
```

notes:

- this method allows a full dynamic prefix, not known in advance. With reversing the strings, it's also possible to remove the common suffix.
- it's better to use `len` to slice the result instead of `str.replace()`: it's faster, and it only removes the start of the string, and safe since we *know* that all strings start by this prefix.

Comment: Is there any different way than `len()`?

Comment: `len()` is way faster than `str.replace`

Comment: The delimiter doesn't matter here? Docs say it's only for path strings

Comment: no, it's slightly abusing this tool, but it doesn't care about path delimiter or such. When computing common directories with that tool, you have to remove what's after the last separator in case all files start by the same prefix!! of course it can be recoded. but in that case, I wouldn't have answered.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre _faster_ from the performance point of view?

Comment: @KamilZabielski: yes. Slicing just creates a new string. replacing tests the input string (which is always there). Moreover, you would need a regex or if the pattern is somewhere else in the string, it could be replaced twice.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well, I was thinking about `len()` as well. it's quite pure and easy solution. I just was thinking there is any kind of better way, like `difference` on `sets`.

Comment: I'm curious as to which `os.path.commonprefix()` or `str.find()` is faster. :)

Comment: `os.path.commonprefix()` is more complex than `str.find`. It's a double loop to test all prefix lengths from 1 to `min(len(x) for x in strings)`. Probably not coded in python, so fast enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehensions, which are pretty pythonic:

```
[newstr.replace(str1, '', 1) for newstr in list_of_strings]
```

`newstr.replace(str, '', 1)` will only replace the first occurance of str1.
Thanks to @ev-kounis for suggesting it

Comment: String replacement with empty-one is good enough solution.Thanks. It will be properly if and only if `<common-part>` is unique by each element of the list, but in this case it actually is.

Comment: That'll leave the hyphen after the common part, by the way

Comment: I also believe that the hyphen here, would be included in the common part.

Comment: Maybe, but what about if `str1` exists twice in the string?

Comment: `newstr.replace(str1, '', 1)` would solve the problem @KamilZabielski is refering to. Notice the `1` in there. That tells Python to just replace the `1`st instance **only**.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyList = ["xxx-56", "xxx-57", "xxx-58"]
MyList = [x[len(prefix):] for x in MyList] # for each x in the list, 
                                 # this function will return x[len(prefix):] 
                                 # which is the string x minus the length of the prefix string

print(MyList)

---> ['56', '57', '58']
```

Comment: I was thinking about using `len()`, but I was thinking there is somehow any kind of more clear solution.

Comment: @Kamil, `len(prefix)` is a perfect solution if the values in the string contain the prefix twice

Comment: It would be better to code the `len(prefix)` instead of hardcoding it like that (`4`).

Answer (score 2):

I would have done...

```
common = "Hello_"
lines = ["Hello_1 !", "Hello_2 !", "Hello_3 !"]

new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    # Finding first occurrence of the word we want to remove.
    startIndex = line.find(common) + len(common)
    new_lines.append(line[startIndex:])

print new_lines
```

---

Just testing performance with Jean-François Fabre since we're at it :

```
from timeit import timeit
import os

def test_fabre(lines):
    # import os

    commonprefix = os.path.commonprefix(lines)
    return [x[len(commonprefix):] for x in lines]

def test_insert(common, lines):
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        startIndex = line.find(common) + len(common)
        new_lines.append(line[startIndex:])
    return new_lines

print timeit("test_insert(common, lines)", 'from __main__ import test_insert; common="Hello_";lines = ["Hello_1 !", "Hello_2 !", "Hello_3 !"]')
print timeit("test_fabre(lines)", 'from __main__ import test_fabre; lines = ["Hello_1 !", "Hello_2 !", "Hello_3 !"]')

# test_insert outputs : 2.92963575145
# test_fabre outputs : 4.23027790484 (with import os OUTside func)
# test_fabre outputs : 5.86552750264 (with import os INside func)
```

Comment: note that your solution removes the word but also what's _before_ it. well, maybe there's nothing before it.

Comment: You're right, that's a side effect I haven't thought about. Thinking about it, only len would be enough considering what I wrote. I will update the answer when I'll be behind a computer. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "hello"
list1 = ["hello1", "hello2", "hello3"]
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    list2.append(i.replace(str1,""))
print list2
```

this is the easiest way you can do.

Comment: Should this work on `hellohello` to only return `hello`?

Comment: @cricket_007 it will work and give [''] as asked in question that we have to remove the str1 nowhere mentioned that how many time it should occur.

Comment: The question did ask for only replacing a common prefix, though

Comment: it is basically unclear because user didn't explain this thing in detail whether to remove it once or more than once, but his example shows once. So basically we cannot say like once or more than once.

Comment: I'm not saying this is wrong, just pointing out the edge case

Comment: Yes definitely. Thanks for giving me a new direction to think. :)